# How to retrieve data from database to display it in csv format on a webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Actually I want to display data in csv format on a web page . Data is stored in message field in the database.
The data is :

```
data    count 
120     80
140     50
170     100
150     70
180     120
```

I want to display this data on a webpage in csv format separated by comma like: data , count .
I found this code on some other site but rather than displaying data on a webpage it make the csv file in folder and store the data in it .
here is the code:

```
// open connection to mysql database   
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or 
die("Connection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

// fetch mysql table rows   
$sql = "select message from wholesaler";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Selection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

$fp = fopen('books.csv', 'w');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}    
fclose($fp);

//close the db connection    
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Can anyone tell me the steps to resolve it ?

Comment: What is comma separated the lines of data or the individual numbers. If you could provide an example output that would be helpful.

Comment: Replace this code 

`$fp = fopen('books.csv', 'w');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}    
fclose($fp);`

with this

`$data = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}    
var_dump($data);`

and add the var_dump output here in comment or to the question.

Comment: output is coming in the array form. here is the output:array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["content"]=> string(47) "data count 120 80 140 50 170 100 150 70 180 120" } }

Answer (score 0):

Code you provided use the loop to save data into CSV file. Because you don't need to save it in a file then you have to replace this loop with some code printing rows on your output.

According to your code you need to replace this part

```
$fp = fopen('books.csv', 'w');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
```

with for example this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    //we need to split your message into array
    $csvRows = explode("\n", $row['message']);

    $head = [];
    if (array_key_exists(0, $csvRows)) {
        $head = explode(' ', trim($csvRows[0]));
    }

    $data = [];
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($csvRows); $i++) {
        $data[] = explode(' ', trim($csvRows[$i]));
    }

    //print recognized headers
    echo '<table width="100%"><tr>';
    foreach ($head as $h) {
        echo "<th>{$h}</th>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    //print your csv row as table row
    foreach ($data as $r) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($r as $v) {
            echo "<td>{$v}</td>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '<table>';
}
```

Comment: It is working . can you tell me what to do to print data in column format?like this :data count
120 80
140 50
170 100
150 70
180 120

Comment: I've changed my answer by adding the code for a table. This code is very simple - it's not checking is every row has the same number of columns and show very simple table but you can use it as a base for your solution.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table  ....  I want something like this table . I tried your above code but i'm not getting this kind of output . can youhelp me out ?

Comment: I;ve changed my answer. You need to change column names (like Column 1 in my example) to your names.

Comment: But column names are data and count and their corresponding values are 120 80 and so on. They are stored in message field of the database as raw data. So i want to display a table like this : data count and their corresponding values .

Comment: You wrote a data like `data count 120 80 140 50 170 100 150 70 180 120` so I thought that one message value is like whole string `data count 120 80 140 50 170 100 150 70 180 120`. I've changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this . But if i enter anything in the message field along with their respective columns then i want to fetch their own column name in table header not data and count every time as table header . Like if i enter  this in message field date value
2013-01 53
2013-02 165
2013-03 269
2013-04 344
2013-05 376
then i want date and value as their table header . Basically i want to fetch it dynamically. what to do in this case ?

Comment: Please improve your question post with all you nead. Can you write your samples data with rows and columns? You write it in one line so it's hard to guess where is the row break.

Comment: See if i enter the data as mentioned in the question in the message field then it stored in one line . And I want to retrieve the data from message field in way that display the data in column format as mentioned in the question in the question.

Comment: I've changed your question so you can see how to show your data with rows. It will be easier for me if you show me your `message` values as separate strings or even better provide it like an PHP array that I can simply use it with my script.

Comment: I changed the message field name to content.                                                                       Here is the code for textfield:                                                                                  <div class="form-group">
              <input id="name" type="text" name="content" placeholder="content*" class="form-control">
            </div>  and when i enter the content it stored like this :       data count 120 80 140 50 170 100 150 70 180 120

Comment: when i enter data in the content filed it stored like a paragraph in content field in the data base.It would be very thankful of you , if you solve this problem .

Comment: I've changed my code to handle with your data and dynamically recognize column headers.

Comment: I doesn't change anything except the spacing  i,m still getting output in a single row. I want output like : table header in one row data,count or data count and their 1st values in 2nd row like 120, 80 or 120 80 and so on.

Comment: I didn't see a line break in your var_dump and forgot about it. I've changed my code.

Comment: No problem :) Remeber to accept answer if provided correct soultion.

Comment: Finally its working!! I directly stored data in message field in column format .Thanx a ton @zajonc , you really helped me a lot , you're great man.          But when I copy the data which is in column format in the message field on a webpage then it stores in a row-wise manner . How to store the data in the message field in column-wise manner ?

Comment: I can ask another question after 6 days .can you tell me how to pass the URL of the page on which data is displayed to c3.js to generate its chart ?  I have a display page on which there is a button Display csv and on clicking it goes to view1.php on which data is displayed . Here is  the display.php code link :https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BziLRtJqUseIemd5cm1TMEZLLVk                                                                      Is the url which i have generated is corrrect ?

Comment: I don't know how your view1.php so I can't tell you is it ok or not. About pasting a data into message field it's depend on how you get this data and insert it into db (including PHP configuration). Try to escape new line before you save it in database and restore after you get it back.

Comment: View1.php is exactly your above code including connection to the database.

Comment: Code above doesn't use a `$_GET['id']` value so you didn't show us all of code or your code just ignore this input value.

Comment: the url is working . I corrected my mistake. can you tell me how to pass the url of a webpage into c3.js to draw it's chart ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know anything about c3.js. I've never use it.