# how to pass dynamic url in c3.js?

Tags: php, c3.js

There is one page on which data is displayed in csv format. And when I'm passing this url in `c3.js` then I'm not getting proper output.

### Here is the code of `c3.html`:

```
<html>     
<head>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c3.css">
</head>

<body>  
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>     
    <script src="c3.min.js"></script>       
    <script>    
        var chart = c3.generate({
            data: {
                url: 'view1.php/id=34.csv',
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

When I run this script then Ii get a output like this:[image]

Output of view1.php?id=34.csv is :[image]
and code of view1.php is : [image]
Can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Typo in the url? `/` instead of `?`

Comment: try changing data.url to `view1.php?id=34.csv`

Comment: i used / in the url . this is the url: view1.php/id=34.csv

Comment: @gattsbr i used ? instead of / and still getting the same output.

Comment: ok if you go to the url in your browser directly, does the csv file come up, or do you get an error?

Comment: When i enter the data in database then it is displayed in csv format on view1.php?id=34.csv page. like this:                                                                             data,count
120,80
140,50
170,100
150,70
180,120                                                                                                              in a proper csv format verticaaly.

Comment: It looks like in the image you are getting a table back, not csv, you need raw text, if you go to the url and view source is there anything except the csv?

Comment: @gattsbr I've updated my question with complete code and complete output . You can see the question once again.

Comment: if that follows the code on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463438/how-to-retrieve-data-from-database-to-display-it-in-csv-format-on-a-webpage) Then you'll need to change it to not output a table, but instead just print the raw text.

Comment: sorry but i was unable to understand what you were just said.

Comment: if you go to `view1.php?id=34.csv` in your browser, and then *right click > view source* is there html for a table there or is it just raw text?

Comment: That is the problem then. You need the raw text, not the table.

Comment: Then how to do this ?

Comment: I think if you change your php file to just echo each row with line breaks and nothing but it should work.

Comment: You have to remove all the html. so basically where ever you end a row `</tr>`, you would print a `\n`, and whenever you close a cell `</td>|</th>` you would need to print a comma `,`

Comment: you should get something then like `data,count\n120,80\n140,50\n170,100\n150,70\n180,120` except all of your `\n` will have been escaped to newlines (otherwise make sure that it's in double quotes `"` not single quotes `'`)

Comment: data,count\n\n,120,80\n\n,140,50\n\n,170,100\n\n,150,70\n\n,180,120\n    it print like this

Comment: can you add your php file's code (w/o passwords)?

Comment: view1.php is already uploaded .

Comment: only the top half of it is.

Comment: Do you want me to reupload my view1.php without passworrd?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the image you are getting a table back, not csv, you need raw text, not an html table.
Try this for your output in your php file:

```
//print recognized headers
for ($i = 0; $i < count($head); $i++) {
    echo $head[$i];
    echo $i == (count($head)-1) ? "\n" : ",";
}

//print your csv row as table row
foreach ($data as $r) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($r); $i++) {
        echo $r[$i];
        echo $i == (count($r)-1) ? "\n" : ",";
    }
}
```

Comment: is it? or is there an extra element (due to the extra , at the end)?

Comment: yup there is an extra element.

Comment: ok, we need to use a loop that doesn't print the comma on the last element then

Comment: Can you tell me how to insert the data in database with line breaks.           for example : the data at the insertion time is this - data,count
120,80
140,50
170,100
150,70
180,120                                    and after the insertion data will appear like a table . Then how to do this ?

Comment: @abhisheksharma try that updated code to not have the extra element.